# How i can add data from table into list view in wpf using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

Here i am reading data from database table and populating into list view .The problem in this code is that the i don't the command for adding data into list view . Here is my code

```
try      
                {
                    Query = "select Id,Description from SaleItemList";
                    lvwmodify.Items.Clear();
                    cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr != null || dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            String[] str = new String[2];
                            str[0] = dr.GetString(0);
                            str[1] = dr.GetString(1);
                            lvwmodify.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(str));  ///Here is error

                        }
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("No Account Found!");
                }
                catch { }
```

Please Help to adding data to list view ?list view is previously filled with some old data will this  ( lvwmodify.Items.Clear(); ) command will make list empty?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below Code:
Assuming you have Data table dt

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["abc"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["xyz"].ToString());
        lvwmodify.Items.Add(listitem);
    }
```